# Fashion MNIST Dataset - KNN classifier - Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, knn

Hello I am at the first steps of machine learning and this is my first tutorial/small project that i am trying to do. I want to use Nearest Neighbor method in the Fashion MNIST Dataset but i am having an error. I know that maybe my question is a bit silly but its the first time that im doing something like that.
so my code is

```
fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,algorithm='auto',n_jobs=10)
clf.fit(train_images,train_labels)

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

As I understand this error is because the train_images is 3d and the train_labels is 2d. What is a good way to reshape it.
Is one of the following right ways?

```
train_images.reshape(-1,1)
```

or

```
nsamples, nx, ny = train_images.shape    
train_images.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a tuple to fit() function. Can you try as below?

```
train,test = fashion_mnist.load_data()
clf.fit(train[0],train[1])
```

or:

```
train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels = fashion_mnist.load_data()
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,algorithm='auto',n_jobs=10)
clf.fit(train_images,train_labels)
```

Comment: I tried both of them and none worked. 
The first one has the same error as previously

and the second one it's not right 
error -> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
in the first line that u wrote above